# How to store parts of a javascript object into variables?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am new to javascript and I have the following object:

```
Stats: {
 "life": {
  "progress": 18,
  "counter": 1
 },
 "anxiety": {
  "progress": 24.5,
  "counter": 2
 },
 "mood": {
  "progress": null,
  "counter": 0
 },
 "cognition": {
  "progress": null,
  "counter": 0
 }
}
```

I'm needing to check if the counter for anxiety, mood, and cognition are > 0, and if they are I must return True.  How can I iterate over this object and check for these specific parts of the object?
Expected output for this would be

```
false
```

If I am to update the object:

```
Stats: {
 "life": {
  "progress": 18,
  "counter": 1
 },
 "anxiety": {
  "progress": 24.5,
  "counter": 2
 },
 "mood": {
  "progress": null,
  "counter": 1
 },
 "cognition": {
  "progress": null,
  "counter": 1
 }
}
```

I want to return

```
True
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?  Why do you need to iterate over anything if there's no array here?  Why not just write an `if` condition that accesses the intended properties directly?

Comment: Try this `Object.values(stats).every(elm => elm.counter > 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the properties to check in an array, use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to filter out the properties that aren't included in the array, then use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check whether each object's `counter` property is greater than 0.

```js
const keysToCheck = ["anxiety", "mood", "cognition"]

function validate(obj){
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => keysToCheck.includes(key)).every(key => obj[key].counter > 0);
}

console.log(validate({
 "life": {
  "progress": 18,
  "counter": 1
 },
 "anxiety": {
  "progress": 24.5,
  "counter": 2
 },
 "mood": {
  "progress": null,
  "counter": 0
 },
 "cognition": {
  "progress": null,
  "counter": 0
 }
}))
```

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted your answer.  However, when i go to return the results of this ```return validate(obj)``` it will return true or false.  However, when I call this function and try to take the value as true/false, it does not work? Is this something that is common? but when I return just true/false it works fine.

Comment: @guitarman Would you mind sharing your code? E.g., putting it in a JsFiddle or editing your post. I'd be happy to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code helping you

```
var obj =  {Stats: {
 "life": {
  "progress": 18,
  "counter": 1
 },
 "anxiety": {
  "progress": 24.5,
  "counter": 2
 },
 "mood": {
  "progress": null,
  "counter": 0
 },
 "cognition": {
  "progress": null,
  "counter": 0
 }
}}

Object.values(obj.Stats).every(o=> o.counter > 0)
```

Comment: *"I'm needing to check if the counter for anxiety, mood, and cognition are > 0"* - this will check every property's `counter` property.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const keysToCheck = ["anxiety", "mood", "cognition"]

function validate(obj){
   let res = 0;
   keysToCheck.forEach(key =>{ if(obj[key].counter > 0) res++; })
   return res == keysToCheck.length;
}

console.log(validate({
 "life": {
  "progress": 18,
  "counter": 1
 },
 "anxiety": {
  "progress": 24.5,
  "counter": 2
 },
 "mood": {
  "progress": null,
  "counter": 0
 },
 "cognition": {
  "progress": null,
  "counter": 0
 }
}))




console.log(validate({
 "life": {
  "progress": 18,
  "counter": 1
 },
 "anxiety": {
  "progress": 24.5,
  "counter": 2
 },
 "mood": {
  "progress": null,
  "counter": 1
 },
 "cognition": {
  "progress": null,
  "counter": 1
 }
}))
```

Answer (score -3):

This code will loop over your object and check it

```
for(var a in stats){
   if(stats[a] == ("anxiety"||"cognition"))
      if(stats[a]["counter"] > 0)
          return true
      else
          return false
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.